# Reporting a list in behaviorspace Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I want to capture the agent set of agent variable X in behaviorspace.

```
to-report MeanOfX
report mean [X] of turtles 
end

to-report AgentSetOfX
report [X] of turtles 
end
```

After I run the experiment I am not getting the same mean of my agent set, and also weird numbers. Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: if you are trying to have BehaviorSpace report something, you will need to show us your BehaviorSpace dialogue box. Also, an agentset is a set of agents, not of variables, so I am not entirely sure what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,  those reporters will report the mean value of X for your turtles and a LIST of the X VALUES for the turtles, like "[ 1 34 3 4 8 92 ]"    It will not return an "agent-set" containing a SET of TURTLES themselves despite your name.    Did you want such an agent-set for some reason?

If you are using any randomization at all anywhere there is no reason the means should come out the same for different runs.  If you need the randomization-generated X values to be identical across runs you should set "random-seed" to some value in your setup.

if the values of X are "weird numbers" you need to debug using some logic or printing out the X values as you generate them to see where they deviate from not being weird.